# Why do emails sent with Gmail from an alias not appear in the sent items?

Tags: email, gmail, google-apps

I have an email address set up on a certain domain, and I have added an alias email address in my Google Apps account set up on another domain. I've also added that alias on the second domain to "Send mail as" to be able to send emails from that email address.

Problem is that when I send emails from that alias, they don't appear in the sent items. Why is this? How can I resolve it?

Comment: Are you sure you're actually sending email through Google Apps' servers? "Send mail as" sounds like a feature that just changes the From address on outgoing mail.

Comment: You can check by sending an email to check-auth@verifier.port25.com - the line starting with "HELO hostname" will tell you which server did the sending.

Answer (score 5):

i just figured it out and it now works, even previously sent mails from an alias via gmail also appear in my sent messages.

in gmail, go to settings, account and imports, in the "send mail as" section, click on "edit info" next to the account which you are having the problem with.
on the screen which pops up, uncheck the radio box for "treat as an alias" dont change any other info, click next step, enter your password and click save changes.

thats all it took to sort out my issue.

best regards

Answer (score 1):

They way I'm reading this is: you've added an [alias/secondary in Google Apps account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53295), example.com, for another domain you own, test.com. After doing this, you [created an email alias](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33327) for your Google Apps user and [setup a send as address](https://support.google.com/a/answer/22370) for @test.com within your @example.com account.

If this is the case, the expected behavior is: emails you send from your example.com account as your test.com account **will** appear in the 'Sent Mail' label for your example.com account. I've just double checked this to confirm.

Can you please provide your exact steps to reproduce the issue if the above isn't correct or you're seeing different behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Sign in to your Google Apps email.
Click the  in the upper-right and select Settings along the top of any page, and select the Accounts tab.
Under Send mail as, click Add another email address.
In the Email address field, enter your name and alternate email address.
Click Next Step >> and then click Send Verification. Gmail will send a verification message to your other email address to confirm that you own it.
Locate the message from Gmail. Open it and and either click the link contained in the message or enter the confirmation code in the Accounts section of your Google Apps email settings.

Then select 
**When replying to a message:
    Reply from the same address the message was sent to**